# MongoDb The handle is invalid

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoimport

I am trying to import a JSON file into MongoDb using Mongoimport.  It throws the following error Failed: error processing document #1: read C:\Users\mbryant2\Documents\primer-dataset.json: The handle is invalid.

Here is my cmd:

$ mongoimport --db tempTestDb --collection restaurants --drop --file C:/Users/mbryant2/Documents/primer-dataset.json

and response:

2018-09-14T12:17:36.337-0600    connected to: localhost
2018-09-14T12:17:36.338-0600    dropping: tempTestDb.restaurants
2018-09-14T12:17:36.339-0600    Failed: error processing document #1: read C:\Users\mbryant2\Documents\primer-dataset.json: The handle is invalid.
2018-09-14T12:17:36.339-0600    imported 0 documents

Anyone have any ideas on what I am missing? Is it needing login credentials or something like that?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: json file you are importing must contain valid json data. check that

Comment: it is a valid json file

Comment: can you share your json or an example of it?

Comment: {"_id":{"$oid":"59074c7c057aaffaafb0da64"},"address":{"building":"2911","coord":[-73.982241,40.576366],"street":"West   15 Street","zipcode":"11224"},"borough":"Brooklyn","cuisine":"Italian","grades":[{"date":{"$date":"2014-12-18T00:00:00.000Z"},"grade":"A","score":13},{"date":{"$date":"2014-05-15T00:00:00.000Z"},"grade":"A","score":12},{"date":{"$date":"2013-06-12T00:00:00.000Z"},"grade":"A","score":9},{"date":{"$date":"2012-02-06T00:00:00.000Z"},"grade":"A","score":9}],"name":"Gargiulo's Restaurant","restaurant_id":"40365784"}

Comment: That just 1 of the 3000

Answer (score 0):

If the data is represented as a JSON array, rather than individual lines of JSON text, you will need to add the `--jsonArray` parameter to mongoimport.